# Hibernate Search boost with values from other table

Tags: hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search, nhibernate-search

I'm using hibernate search(latest release) with a local Lucene backend.
I have two entities as follows;

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class A {

    @Id
    private Long id; 

    @FullTextField
    private String text;

    @KeywordField
    private String keyword;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    
    private BigDecimal number;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;
}
```

I have mass indexer that handles indexing A entities at the application startup.
While searching I want search results to be ordered by *number* field of entity B.

My search function is a simple boolean predicate as follows

```
.where(f -> f.bool()
          .should(f.match().field("text").matching(query))
          .should(f.match().field("keyword").matching(query.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)))
)
.fetch(offset, limit)
```

What should I do to order/boost search results depending on another field of another entity which has one-to-one relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the word "boost", but I think you're simply after "sorting". "bootsting" is a different concept that affects the score, and only affects the order of hits indirectly.

To sort by this `number` property, you will have to embed it into the index document created for `A`. To that end, use [`@IndexedEmbedded`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexedembedded):

```java
@Entity
@Indexed
public class A {

    @Id
    private Long id; 

    @FullTextField
    private String text;

    @KeywordField
    private String keyword;

    // Add this, and make sure to update it every time you update B.a
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private B b;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    
    private BigDecimal number;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;
}
```

**WARNING:** Make sure that every time you call `b.setA(...)`, you also call `a.setB(...)` so that all entities are consistent. Otherwise, Hibernate Search will not be able to index your data properly.

Then annotate `number` so that it's indexed and [sortable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-directfieldmapping-sortable):

```java
@Entity
public class B {
    
    @GenericField(searchable = Searchable.NO, sortable = Sortable.YES)
    private BigDecimal number;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;
}
```

Then add a [sort](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-sort) to your query:

```java
.where(f -> f.bool()
          .should(f.match().field("text").matching(query))
          .should(f.match().field("keyword").matching(query.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)))
)
.sort(f -> f.field("b.number").asc())
.fetch(offset, limit)
```